# HTML5 JavaScript game start screen Image button replacement

Tags: css, html

I have some code for a basic start screen, But i want to change the button for to a image, How would i do this?

```
<div id="SplashScreen">
<h1>Game Title</h1>
<input id="StartButton" type="button" value="Start"/>
</div>

<canvas id="GameCanvas" style="display: none;">Game Stuff</canvas>

<script>
    $("#StartButton").click(function () {
    $("#SplashScreen").hide();
    $("#GameCanvas").show();
});
</script>
```

So i want the play button to be replaced with a image? Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Ok there is no "play" button in your code. I think you mean the "start" button. Just replace with an image, et voilà `<img id="StartButton" src="whatever.jpg" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
<button type="button" id="StartButton"><img src="image.png" /></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `<img>` tag for your button.

To make it look more like a clickable button, you could use some css

```
#StartButton
{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

so the cursor will look like pointing over on a link

Answer (score 1):

in css.

```
#StartButton {
    background-image:url('yourimagehere.jpg');
}
```